# is there ways to add link items to navigation drawer activity ( build in navigation drawer)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, navigation-drawer

i ve created project with android studio's navigation drawer activity. when adding my ovn fragment and link to it on navigation menu it doesnt work when it clicked, however i did everything same as default given fragments, replaced with my own names. so i'm adding product fragment.
here is my MainActivity.java :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.cw.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_porduct,R.id.nav_gallery)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Here is my ProductFragmen.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.cw.myapplication.databinding.FragmentProductBinding;


public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentProductBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        binding = FragmentProductBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
```

Here is my main_drawer xml file
[image: activity_main_drawer]

Here is fragment_product.xml file

[image: fragment_product.xml]

Comment: go to `navigation` > `mobile_navigation.xml` and add your own custom fragment there and run again.

Comment: @M Dev thanks or helping, its working now!!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding following code to file mobile_navigation.xml located in project directory/res/navigation folder as @M Dev stated (thanks for him and his answer can be found in comments for the question)

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_product"
        android:name="com.cw.myapplication.ui.product.ProductFragment"
        android:label="Product"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_product" />
```